# Codeigniter slash in URL parameters

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a Controller with a method that accepts 2 parameters a username and a password like the following :

```
class Test extends CI_Controller {

    public function index($username= NULL, $password = NULL){
        if($username === NULL){
           echo "Error";          
        }else if($password === NULL){
            echo "Error";
        }else{
            echo "Your username is :"$username." and your password is :".$password;
        }            
    }
}
```

in the route file I'm doing:

```
$route['Upload/(:any)'] = "Test/index/$1";
$route['Upload/(:any)/(:any)'] = "Test/index/$1/$2";
```

and in config file :

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = '';
```

The url looks like: `mysite.com/Test/mike123/rtO;"*skj`

The issue I'm facing is that the password can contain a slashes that can make the url like below and break it:

```
mysite.com/Test/mike123/rtO;"*//skj
```

The url must be run like : mysite.com/Test/param1/param2   I do not want to url encode it. Is there any solution to run the url and get the parameters as `mike123` and `rtO;"*//skj`

Thanks

Comment: Use `url_encode` and `url_decode`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to pass password through URL. DO you know that this is not at all secure. You do not want to encode it either.

I would pass the password through POST which is more secure then passing it directly through URL.

However, If this is what you want you can url_encode the password when passing into this function and again url_decode it back in the function for further use

Comment: what is the portable between languages like PHP and .NET? url_encode and url_decode or rawurlencode and rawurldecode

Answer (score 0):

Send username and password using jquery like this

```
var username = $("#username").val();

var password = $("#password").val();

var datastring ='username='+username+'&password='+password;

$.post(URL,datastring,function(){

});
```